# True or False ? If $U, V, W$ are vector spaces and $U$ is a subspace of $V, W$ is a subspace of $V$ then $W = U$.

Tags: vector-spaces

If $U, V, W$ are vector spaces and $U$ is a subspace of $V, W$ is a subspace of $V$ then $W = U$.

My first intuition would be that this is false. If for example

$V = \Bbb R^3$

$U = \Bbb R^3$ where all values greater than one

$W = \Bbb R^3$ where all values greater than two

$U \ne W$ because  $(1,1,1)$ is not in $W$ since $W$ is all values $> 2$.

Comment: You are right that the statement is false, but the sets you describe are not subspaces (they don't have the zero vector).

Comment: hmmm would it would work if I were to say U is R^3 with values greater than -3 and W having values greater than -2?

Comment: No, those fail scalar multiplication.  Instead, think about lower dimensional spaces.

Comment: More to the point, can you characterize those spaces $V$ for which the statement does hold?

Answer (score 0):

Let $U=\{0\}×\mathbb{R}$ and $W=\mathbb{R}×\{0\}$. Both of these sets are subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^2$, but they are not equal.